# Query using group by and max() will not use index

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, indexing, group-by

I have a very simple query:

```
select id, max(time) AS max_time
    from table
    group by id;
```

i also created an index using id + time:

```
CREATE INDEX table_time_and_id ON table USING (id, time DESC NULLS LAST)
```

(I assume id already has an index as it is an foreign key, time can be NULL)

problem is, if I `explain` the `select`, I see this index has not been used; I am expecting that for every `id` it will have to select only the first element as will already be the `max()`, and be almost immediate; instead it is doing a sequential read and taking about 16 seconds.

I tried to force the use of the index with `SET LOCAL enable_seqscan = off;` and while it is executing and using the correct index, it takes ~1 minute!

Why is this index slowing down instead of making the query much faster? And how can I fix it?

The database is postgreeSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by `I assume id already has an index as primary key` : if it is the primary key, it should be unique ? why are you doing a group by id ?

[It is possible to do this group by](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158015/why-can-i-select-all-fields-when-grouping-by-primary-key-but-not-when-grouping-b), but it is just like

```
select id, time from table
```

Tt should be faster to read the whole table since the query will not have to check the visibility map, [from the documentation about covering indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html)

> In short, while an index-only scan is possible given the two fundamental requirements, it will be a win only if a significant fraction of the table's heap pages have their all-visible map bits set. But tables in which a large fraction of the rows are unchanging are common enough to make this type of scan very useful in practice.

The *two fundamental requirements* are : index type (like btree) allows it, and all columns of the query are inside the index.

and you should also read [the wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Why_isn.27t_my_query_using_an_index-only_scan.3F)

> In Postgres 9.2, statistics are gathered about the proportion of pages that are known all-visible. The pg_class.relallvisible column indicates how many pages are visible (the proportion can be obtained by calculating it as a proportion of pg_class.relpages). These statistics are updated when VACUUM is run. **It is advisable to run VACUUM ANALYZE** immediately after upgrading to PostgreSQL 9.2, in order to ensure that relallvisible roughly accords with reality.

Maybe your statistics are not updated, maybe most of your pages seem not visible.

If you add the index just before doing the query (as a test), maybe it will use the index : [at least sometimes the optimizer will use the fresh index](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8bd76cea5df60e147b6b46110998b59c).

In the fiddle you can see that after a VACUUM ANALYZE, it is faster, and it is faster because there are no **Heap Fetches: 0**. But with only 2 columns in the table the sequential scan is still faster.

Comment: > What do you mean by I assume id already has an index as primary key : if it is the primary key, it should be unique ? why are you doing a group by id ?

you are totally right, I got confused by ID name, but is not a unique key, it is extern key, so there are many

Comment: @Lesto If you have more columns in your table, then the covering index can become faster, does the behaviour change if you do a `VACUUM ANALYZE table` ?

Comment: accepting this as answer, not sure how i forgot about this question, but this is the answer with most information to dig deeper

Answer (score 2):

What you would need is an "index skip scan", or "loose index scan".  But PostgreSQL does not automatically implement those (yet).  You can get one anyway by using a [recursive CTE](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) to force the issue, but that is hard, error-prone, and ugly.  (Fortunately you could wrap it up in a view)

Answer (score 1):

First, let me point out that the Postgres optimizer is doing what it should be doing.  It is choosing the best optimization plan, despite your best efforts to get around it.  But . . . that doesn't answer your question.

Normally, when indexes are used in Postgres, the engine needs to check the original data pages to see if the values are visible to the current transaction.  This is needed to support the ACID properties of databases, where data is being both modified and queried at the same time.  (I should note that this is only one way to implement these properties.)

Postgres has supported index-only scans for a while -- but they assume that all rows are visible to the current transaction.  This is often true in relatively static databases, particularly if they are vacuum'ed after any changes.

If the rows are not known to be visible, then both the index *and the original data* need to be read.  Reading the original data out-of-order imposes additional overheads, particularly in a memory-limited environment.  That is, if the entire table does not fit into available memory, then you end up "thrashing".  But even just reading the table out-of-order is more expensive than scanning it.

You can read more about index-only scans in the [documentation](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#:%7E:text=Index%2Donly%20scans%20are%20a,O%20necessary%20to%20satisfy%20queries.).

Comment: the index i am using, table_time_and_id, contains all the fields i need.  
Also i see how you will end up having many small random access instead of maybe lesser but larger sequential read, BUT i now for each ID there are tens of thousands of recorded times, so a sparse read should be way more effective in this case, that is what puzzle me.
I was thinking instead to create a `material view` with only the max value for each index, but then i will have to make sure to manually update it every time the `table` changes.

Answer (score 1):

Index scan is perfect if reduce table scan to minimum (when only smaller part of table should be read from disc). When result is bigger, then index scan is slower than seq scan. Index scan uses slower random IO and iterate over table in random order. Seq scan uses seq IO, that is faster than random IO, but complete table data file should be read from disk.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has a very advanced intelligence system, it is generally preferable to allow it to choose the best form of indexing.

it is likely that he chose to ignore his index because it gets faster.

In any case, create your index and prepare it, if Postgres sees fit, it will use it.

Sorry for my bad English